# non persistent check of dict array

Tags: php, mysql

Some strange is going on, cant quite point my finger why.

Array $regions is a reverse dictionary of regions [regionCode => regionID]. In function parse_r() where is a check for new regionCode, if so - this regionCode added to dictionary. This is a only place to add new region. But sometimes (maybe 1 from 50 cases) new row added with previously existed region name. regionCode is a text, non unique field.

Why this is happening, what am I doing wrong?

```
function reps() {
global $mysqli;
$regions=get_regions();
...
$status = parse_r($filename);
...
}

function get_regions() {
global $mysqli;
$regions=array();
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `regionCodes` ORDER BY `regionCodes`.`id` DESC';
  $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
  if( $res !== false ) { 
     while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
       $regions[$row['regionCode']]=$row['id'];
     }
  }
return $regions;
}

function parse_r($filenameFull) {
global $mysqli, $regions;
  $r['regionCode']=$ttt['regionCode'];
  if ( !(array_key_exists($r['regionCode'], $regions))  ) {
     $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `regionCodes`(`regionCode`) VALUES ('%s')", $mysqli->real_escape_string($r['regionCode']) );
     $res = $mysqli->query($sql);
     $regions=get_regions();
  }
  $r['regionID'] = $regions[$r['regionCode']];
```

Comment: What looks the same may not necessarily always be the same. Did you check for spaces or non-printable characters? You should also trim the $r['regionCode'], etc...

Comment: In mysql base search by regionCode=.. displays all rows with same regionCode. Dont know if its a proper postfactum check...  Also this trick ` ORDER BY `regionCodes`.`id` DESC'` insures that $r['regionID'] is always a lowest value